# Cosa significa e dove si usa l'espressione "acca 24"?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

Giulia e Arianna parlano di Laura:

> Giulia: "Laura è eccessivamente impegnata nelle questioni sociali".
>
> Arianna: "Si, è vero! Il suo impegno ***acca 24*** inizia proprio ad
> urtarmi".
>
> Giulia: "Cosaaa! ***acca 24***?!"

Come si evince dal dialogo descritto, Giulia non comprende cosa significhi ***acca 24***, forse perché è un'espressione che non si usa nei luoghi in cui ha vissuto.

Sapreste indicarmi se l'espressione ***acca24*** è comunemente compresa in Italia, oppure se il suo uso è limitato ad alcune regioni?

Comment: Credo sia antecedente al discorso dei "maroni" e che sia nata in ambiente militare.

Comment: Secondo me Giulia capisce cosa ha detto Arianna, ma trova ridicola l'espressione usata.

Comment: @Kyriakos Giulia capisce ciò che Arianna ha detto

Comment: 24 heures sur 24 en français

Answer (score 19):

L'espressione *H24* è entrata solo recentemente nel parlare comune e non è assolutamente accettata in un testo scritto. Il significato è *24 ore su 24*.

È un'espressione dialettale tipica del nord Italia diventata di uso comune dopo che il Presidente della Regione Lombardia Roberto Maroni la utilizzò più volte durante la campagna elettorale 2013.

Il comico Crozza ne esaltò la "milanesità" durante i suoi show e permise all'espressione di diffondersi in tutto il paese. Per interesse tutto nacque da [questo video che trovi nel Corriere](http://video.corriere.it/dobbiamo-fare-pulizia/f0b21d0a-8351-11e1-b660-48593c628107).

Comment: Dire *non è assolutamente accettata* mi sembra improprio; io direi *è inaccettabile* che esprime la tua opinione (e anche la mia).

Comment: Secondo l'Accademia della Crusca, in parole di Vittorio Coletti (si veda risposta sotto), si tratta in effetti di un'espressione da evitare. Coletti arriva persino ad affermare: «Bisognerebbe dunque evitare la sequenza h24 e a maggior ragione H24, che, in ogni caso, solo un lettore automatico male addestrato o un giornalista incompetente può leggere “accaventiquattro” e non, come si deve, ventiquattrore.»

Answer (score 6):

Immagino sia usato come sinonimo di "24 ore su 24", "costante".

Sinceramente come espressione mutuata dall'inglese "H24" la trovo molto milanese, ma soprattutto alquanto ridicola.

Comment: Soprattutto perchè in inglese non si dice così... (24/7 è l'espressione utilizzata)

Answer (score 5):

*Acca 24* means *24 ore al giorno*, and it is used to mean something done constantly and many times in a day. It comes from the name given to H in Italian, which stays for *hours*. It doesn't come from English, since in English you say *24/7* (24 hours per day, 7 days per week).

I disagree with you saying that Giulia doesn't understand the expression; I read it more than astonishment, in a negative way, about what Laura does. What I would expect after *Cosa! Acca 24?!* would be something on the lines of *Ma è tutta scema!*

I have never heard the expression being widely used outside the context said from leoredi. Knowing English, I would probably understand it on the given context, but I am not sure everybody would understand it. It cannot even be considered a neologism.

Comment: Mi sembra un inglese computerizzato e anche italianizzato...

Answer (score 3):

È entrato nell'uso comune scritto come H24 per indicare un impegno o un servizio continuo. Per esempio, alcuni call center richiedono di lavorare sui tre turni canonici o su diverse composizioni di part time per coprire il servizio 24 ore su 24; nell'uso comune si indica come un servizio H24; idem, per esempio, alcuni servizi di viglianza, il pronto soccorso e servizi simili.

Ha ragione chi dice che in inglese non si usa, poiché generalmente nei paesi anglosassoni si usa l'espressione 24/7, ma c'è una differenza sostanziale: 24/7 significa 24 ore su 24, 7 giorni su 7, quindi sempre, mentre H24 da noi si usa per indicare un impegno o una copertura di 24 ore nella giornata.

Un esempio pratico posso fornirlo descrivendo un servizio che un'azienda eroga in reperibilità quando l'ufficio è chiuso. Nei giorni feriali (ufficio aperto) hai la reperibilità al di fuori dell'orario canonico (supponiamo 9 - 18), mentre nel weekend, non essendoci l'ufficio la reperibilità diventa H24.

Quindi 24/7 e H24 non sono equivalenti.

Answer (score 1):

Secondo questa recente [risposta di Vittorio Coletti per l'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/come-si-abbrevia-come-si-scrive-e-come-si-legge-24-ore-su-24/2777), si tratta di un'espressione per indicare le ventiquattrore del giorno che si dovrebbe evitare e sostituire da altre qui proposte. Questo tipo di espressioni abbreviate si sono cominciate a usare in tempi recenti, da quando ci sono negozi, servizi ecc. aperti tutto il giorno:

> L’abbreviazione di *ora* è la *h* iniziale minuscola del latino *hora* (e non dell’inglese *hour*) e dovrebbe seguire il numero (18h= sei del pomeriggio) e non precederlo, allo stesso modo della *m* di minuto (es.:18h,30m). (Tra parentesi: in latino *hora* seguiva il numero ordinale che la indicava). Bisognerebbe dunque evitare la sequenza h24 e a maggior ragione H24, che, in ogni caso, solo un lettore automatico male addestrato o un giornalista incompetente può leggere “accaventiquattro” e non, come si deve, ventiquattrore. Oggi, in verità, si nota sempre più spesso *h* anteposto, specie quando non indica le ore del giorno, ma un monte ore, una somma di ore: “il corso dura h 60”. Quanto al modo migliore per scrivere sinteticamente che un servizio è aperto tutto il giorno, dopo il chiaro e persino ridondante *24 ore su 24* (basterebbe *24 ore*), che non è poi troppo lungo, anche quelli indicati da una lettrice vanno bene, eccetto, a rigore, come detto, quelli con *h* anteposta e/o maiuscola; e quindi: *24h su 24* o *24h/24h*. Però, è ormai così frequente questo avviso che si finisce per omettere ogni abbreviazione di *ora* e si scrive *24/24*, anche perché il riferimento non è alle ore *24* ma alle *ventiquattrore*, un’indicazione oraria della cui abbreviazione si è sentita l’esigenza in tempi recenti (da quando ci sono negozi, servizi ecc. aperti tutto il giorno) e che ha il vantaggio della brevità e della decifrabilità in qualsiasi lingua (allo stesso modo *7/7* è intuitivamente interpretato come “tutti i giorni”). Anche nei telegrafici messaggini è raro che si scriva: “partenza 18h,30m”, ma quasi sempre: “partenza 18,30”. Il fatto è che quello delle *ore* è ormai uno dei numeri che capita più spesso di scrivere e di leggere, interpretandolo (ad esempio sui display digitali) anche solo grazie all’ordine in una sequenza: 18:30:15 vale ore 18, minuti 30, secondi 15. Della *h*, pur corretta, si sente sempre meno la necessità. Ma in scritti formali non dimenticherei che *ora*/*ore* è appena più lungo di due lettere della sintetica *h*! Per concludere, propongo un caso di bella convivenza di due sistemi per indicare le ore, in un saggio scientifico del 2014, che troviamo nel Corpus CORIS: “Osservando l’andamento della pressione durante il giorno, quando le condizioni del tempo sono buone, si nota che essa è diversamente distribuita nelle *ventiquattro ore*, toccando due massimi circa le *10h* e le *22h*, e due minimi circa le *4h* e le *16h*”.